# Remove empty objects from json array

Tags: arrays, json

my json array has below elements.

```
RuleConfigs.attributeContainers[{},{name: "Ref_Registration", value: "ref_registration", uuid: "b2b0a360-3e4a-97fd-fba2-c1aeb8f31580"}]
```

I want to remove empty objects before this send to database. how can I do this?

i want below result

```
RuleConfigs.attributeContainers[{name: "Ref_Registration", value: "ref_registration", uuid: "b2b0a360-3e4a-97fd-fba2-c1aeb8f31580"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#filter` to remove object with no property using `Object.keys()`.

```js
var arr = [{},{name: "Ref_Registration", value: "ref_registration", uuid: "b2b0a360-3e4a-97fd-fba2-c1aeb8f31580"}],
    result = arr.filter(o => Object.keys(o).length);
console.log(result);
```